# Django Datetime.strptime displays unwanted time

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to inject a date into my django html template.

I have the string `"2019-05-26"` and I am trying to convert it to datetime format for django to display as `"May 26, 2019"` on the webpage. The problem is that it displays `"May 26, 2019 Midnight"` instead of just `"May 26 2019"`. It adds the `"Midnight"` because of a trailing 00:00 that is added on from the function, How do I remove the trailing `"midnight"`?

```
timestamp = transaction["timestamp"]
data = (timestamp[:10]) if len(timestamp) > 10 else timestamp
print(data)
data2 = datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

> print("timestamp:", transaction["timestamp"])
>
> timestamp: 2019-05-26T20:55:44.993368+00:00

Comment: Can you show where you *render* the timestamp (the relevant part of the template)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.strptime()` returns a datetime object. You just need the date, so call the `date()` method.

```
data2 = datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = datetime.strptime("2019-05-26", '%Y-%m-%d')
print(data)
```